# result of closure in function to variable in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I've got a function which does an asynchrone call

```
func getToken(completionHandler:@escaping (_ stringResponse: String) -> Void) {
var testResult: String! = "20,5º"
let url: String! = "https://the.base.url/token"
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "key":"value"
    ]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent)).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        testResult = "21º"
    case .failure(let error):
        testResult = error as! String
    }
    completionHandler(testResult)
}
}
```

And I call this function

```
getToken(completionHandler: {
     (stringResponse: String) in
     print(stringResponse)
     })
```

And it nicely prints 21º as I can see in the debugger. However, the final value of stringResponse should end up in

```
lblTemp.setText(String(//here the results of stringResponse))
```

How do I do this? I'm guessing it must be incredible simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like that

```
getToken(completionHandler: { [weak self] (stringResponse: String) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.lblTemp.text = stringResponse
    }
})
```

Comment: you should also avoid retain cycle, by adding `[weak self]`

Comment: My final code was this `getToken(completionHandler: { (stringResponse: String) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.lblTemp.setText(String(stringResponse))
            }
        })`

Isn't that the same?

Comment: to avoid retain cycle you have to use [weak self] as well

Comment: Two points: First, just to clarify, it's not a strong reference cycle. It's just a strong reference which is resolved when the request finishes. Still, the `[weak self]` is prudent (why hang on to it longer than you need?). Second, you're not referencing `self` in your closure. Perhaps you meant `self?.lblTemp.text = ...`.